# In a HTML page, i want to pick the value of a javascript with jsoup?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, jsoup

```
   <html>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            var map = null;
            jQuery(function($) {
        L.marker([50.065407, 19.945104], {title: 'Cat'})
                            .bindPopup('<h3>Cat</h3><p><strong>color</strong>black<br><strong>Dog</strong>white</p>')
                            .addTo(map);
            </script>
        </html>
```

I need to get values from `<h3>` and `<strong>`.
script = doc.select("script");
but how to get: 
 "Cat color black"
"Dog white" ?

 `p = Pattern.compile("^[a-z]+")`; 
`m = p.matcher(doc.html())`;
 `return String.valueOf(m)`;
 it returns me java.util.regex.Matcher@4167d5f8

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have some html code that contains javascript markers.I need to get some values with jsoup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29864947/i-have-some-html-code-that-contains-javascript-markers-i-need-to-get-some-values)

Comment: Please don't ask the same thing multiple times. For your question, read up on how to use [regex in java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), and google will help also.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
String content = //text you posted above

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".bindPopup\\('(.*)'\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(content);

while (m.find()) {
      String text = m.group(1);

      String htmlStripped = text.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", " ");

      System.out.println(htmlStripped);

}
```

Comment: Next time, do your research _before_ asking here, this is really simple with just a little effort.